# jinja2.exception in an if statement in HTML code

Tags: python, html, jinja2

For my school project, I use `Jinja2` in HTML and Python in the backend. I got this error:

```
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: expected token ':', got '}
```

And this was my code in `.html` for this error to occur was:

```
<table>
    </tbody>
        {% for food in foodList %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ food["description"] }}</td>
            ...
            <td>
                {% if current_user_id ==  {{ food["user_id"] }} %}
                    <button type="button">Buy Now</button>
                {% else %}
                    <button type="button">Delete</button>
                {% endif %}
            </td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

In the if statement `{{}}` is not allowed as I understood. However, I am unable to get the value stored in food["user_id"] to compare with `current_user_id`. `foodList` is a list from a table formed out of a query.

current_user_id is the session["user_id"] passed from Python backend when rendered and `food["user_id"]` has a `user_id` stored for each item in the database table.

How do a I get rid of this error?

I tried modifying the statement:

```
  {% if current_user_id ==  food["user_id"] %}
```

though the error disappeared, it always, executed the else part of the code, which was not correct.

Comment: the modified condition is the correct syntax, you need to troubleshoot why its going to the `else` block.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [ilias-sp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5736671/ilias-sp), who rightly pointed out. It was a programming error. The backend was not sending the value in current_user-id, which resulted it in ending up with else part of the code. Modified code, which worked, looks like this:

```
    <table>
    </tbody>
        {% for food in foodList %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ food["description"] }}</td>
            ...
            <td>
                {% if current_user_id ==  food["user_id"] %}
                    <button type="button">Buy Now</button>
                {% else %}
                    <button type="button">Delete</button>
                {% endif %}
            </td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```